# Prove by induction that for a natural number a there exists integers $x, y$ where $a = 7x + 2y?$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, induction

I am trying to get my head around induction at the moment and found this problem in a textbook.  I think that I should be doing induction on $a$, but I can't even see where to start the proof.

Comment: Can you show that there exists integers $x, y$ so that $7x + 2y = 1$?

Comment: And to complement the comment by @Arthur, once you've solved that case, you don't need induction any more, just multiplication. Another case of a very bad example to learn induction.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I will do it using two ways

Here is a $\color{blue}{\textbf{semi-induction}}$ proof !
The first natural number is $1$ so this is the base case

Base case: $a=1$

If you want to find $x,y$ such that $1 = 7x +2y$. You just want to apply the euclidean algorithm. Notice that $\gcd(7,2)=1$

$7 = 3(2) + 1$ and so $1 = 7 - 3(2)$ and so $x =1,y =-3$

Now notice that from the equation $1 = 7 -3(2)$ you can multiply by any integer $k$ each side to get the desired result.

For example, $$10 = 7(10) - 30(2)$$ and so in this case $x=10,y =-30$

$$17 = 7(17) - 51(2)$$ and so $x=17,y = -51$ and so on.

And so you don't need complete induction method to prove it.

For $\color{red}{\textbf{complete induction}}$ you need to assume it works for some Natural number $k$ such that there exists integers $x,y$ such that $k = 7x + 2y$.

We now need to prove that it also holds for $k+1$

And so we add $1$ to each side of the equation $$k=7x+2y$$

$k+1 = 7x + 2y +1 = 7(x+1) +2(y-3)$ and so $x^{'} =x+1$ and $y^{'}=y-3$

and so $k+1 = 7x^{'} + 2y^{'}$ for some integers $x^{'},y^{'}$

Wanna try it.

$1=7 -3(2)$ with $x=1,y=-3$ right ?

Now let $x=1+1=2$ and let $y=-3-3=6$   now we have

$2 = (2)7-6(2)$

And so induction is done

Comment: I never even thought of using the gcd, that is very helpful, thank you!

Comment: I did it using induction as well !!  You are very welcome :)

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:**

- Every even number can be representend as $2y$.
- One can be represented as $7-3\cdot2$. How can we get all odd numbers from 
  this?